# Metal api - GPU FPS is 0

Tags: xcode, macos-sierra, metal

I had play around with `Signed Distance Functions` and the frame rate is falling to 30 fps. So I just take a look at the bebugger in `Xcode`:

[image]

and just realize that all the processing is done in `cpu` and seems like `gpu` is not running at all.

Almost all of my code is inside `metal` file with compute shader. `cpu` is just to compile and launch the app.

What could possibly be happening here? Anyway for me to test and inspect this issue?

I am using `macOS` 10.12.2 and `Xcode` 8.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pay too much attention to those gauges; they're both lying to you. The GPU meter always reports 0 utilization on some AMD GPUs, despite the fact that your SDF raymarcher is probably quite taxing on the GPU. The apparently high CPU utilization is actually caused by the fact that the frame time is calculated from the beginning of the frame to the end, rather than the amount of time the CPU is actually busy (e.g., if the GPU takes 30 ms to complete the frame, that will show up as ~30ms on the CPU, even though it was mostly idle during that time). Notice that the CPU utilization is actually only ~3% on the left; this is a more accurate reflection of how little work you're doing to encode the frame.

In short: the gauges are unreliable. Your shader is expensive, and that's why your frame rate is suffering.